# cannot access webapp running in docker

Tags: asp.net, docker

I followed a [tutorial about creating a web-app using Docker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3s-RfwvijpY). My dockerfile exposes port 5000:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
#EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR .
COPY ["CustomerApi/CustomerApi.csproj", "CustomerApi/"]
COPY ["CustomerApi.Domain/CustomerApi.Domain.csproj", "CustomerApi.Domain/"]
COPY ["CustomerApi.Service/CustomerApi.Service.csproj", "CustomerApi.Service/"]
COPY ["CustomerApi.Data/CustomerApi.Data.csproj", "CustomerApi.Data/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CustomerApi/CustomerApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "./CustomerApi"
RUN dotnet build "CustomerApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CustomerApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CustomerApi.dll"]
```

when I run the image locally using

```
docker run myrepo/demo:latest -p 5000:5000 -p 5001:5001 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=https://+:5001 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
```

and open my browser on `https://localhost:5000` I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` (I'm not sure why I need `5001` within my `docker run`-command at all, as it's not exposed within my dockerfile).

When I inspect the image within docker desktop I see this:

[image]

In particular it shows `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+80`, although I overwrote that above using `-e ASPENTCORE_URLS=https://5000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options on `docker run` are split up in 2 parts:

- Options before the image name are docker options
- Options after the
  image name override any CMD and is sent to the container

So your command should look like this

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -p 5001:5001 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=https://+:5001 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000 myrepo/demo:latest
```

EXPOSE doesn't actually *do* anything. It's mostly documentation about what ports you think the container uses. It can be wrong and if it's wrong you don't get any errors or warnings.

Comment: haha, that is ridiculously simple. I'd never thought the order of params had any effect. Thank you for your anser, it works.

Comment: I still don't get the point for that `5001`-port, as it also returns `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` for both `http` and `https`. I assume I don't need it

Comment: I think the correct environment variable name is `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT` (with an 'S'). So yours probably does nothing. If I want both http and https, I only use ASPNETCORE_URLS and set it to `https://+:5001;http://+:5000`.

Comment: hmmm, no `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ` seems to be an invalid variable. And I wasn't able to set `ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001;http://+:5000` (""docker run" requires at least 1 argument."). I also tried to set the value into quotes. But I leave that for another question, thanks again.